# Error while plotting Graphs in R

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R and I request someone to help me with the issues am facing while trying to plot basic graphs in R.

1.) When i try to plot a simple model using my below code, it GIVES THE ERROR AS "Hit  to see next plot:"

```
    data(attitude)
attach(attitude)
lm1<-lm(rating~., data=attitude)
plot(lm1)
```

I went through searching for the solution for this error and i found one related post in this site but the answers were relevant to that particular code(Arithmetic).

2.) While trying to PLOT A HISTOGRAM, I GET AN ERROR as follows :-

Warning messages:

```
1: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/SAICHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsRLDJV/f9ff6e9a81b54223a5653b6dbe0c8aa2.png",  :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/SAICHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsRLDJV/f9ff6e9a81b54223a5653b6dbe0c8aa2.png' for writing
2: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/SAICHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsRLDJV/f9ff6e9a81b54223a5653b6dbe0c8aa2.png",  :
  opening device failed.
```

My code for the above problem is :-

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("E:\\Linear Regression\\Lab\\Day 1")
## data reading and descriptives
HousData <- read.csv("Housing.csv", header=T)
names(HousData)
str(HousData)
summary(HousData)
dim(HousData)

## type conversion
HousData$CHAS = as.factor(HousData$CHAS)

## visualizing relationships 

h<-hist(HousData$MEDV, main = "distribution of median prices of houses", col="green")
```

I AM ATTACHING THE ERROR AND DATA IN THE ATTACHMENTS.

I went through the similar errors in this site but i found that increasing the window size would help sometimes but i even tried that and am still facing the issue.

3.) While i try plotting a density curve for the above code, i get an error as follows :-

```
 "Error in plot.new() : 
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/SAICHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAVUSZy/f2e8548045654958b24c3ce58b415a8d.png' for writing"
```

My code is :-

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("E:\\Linear Regression\\Lab\\Day 1")
## data reading and descriptives
HousData <- read.csv("Housing.csv", header=T)
names(HousData)
str(HousData)
summary(HousData)
dim(HousData)

## type conversion
HousData$CHAS = as.factor(HousData$CHAS)

## visualizing relationships 

h<-hist(HousData$MEDV, main = "distribution of median prices of houses", col="green")
x<- HousData$MEDV
xfit<-seq(min(x),max(x),length=60) 
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)) 
yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(x) 
lines(xfit, yfit, col="blue", lwd=2)

d<- density(HousData$MEDV)
plot(d)
```

THE MAIN THING I GET CONFUSED IS THAT the same code gets executed without error for the rest of my classmates but not for me, not sure why like that.

I was looking for an online community for R like this one and i got signed up just and posting my issues.

I would be SO THANKFUL if someone can help me with my above 3 plotting errors and also help me understand if there is something wrong in the code (or) do i need to follow any steps to avoid such errors.
[image: Linear Regression Errors while plotting]

[image: Linear regression Error]

I have my Data file "HousData", but am unable to find where to attach the file. So, if someone can help me rectify the error by just seeing my code i.e without my data file then COOL. Else if anyone can let me know where to attach the data file, ill attach as soon as i get a response.

Thanks a LOT in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first "Error". Is not an error, the `plot`function on a `lm` model works that way. If you want one plot, use `which` from 1 to 4.

```
plot(lm1,which = 2)
```

Comment: Hi Robert ... Thanks for your time and help. I've tried plotting the graph as you said i.e by using plot(lm1,which = 2). But still am getting an error as below :-

Warning messages:
1: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/SAICHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUTB5b6/3f312518328b4b67b370105d87dd2b20.png",  :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/SAICHA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUTB5b6/3f312518328b4b67b370105d87dd2b20.png' for writing
  opening device failed

I think the issue is something related to my directory. Request you to see the error and help me.

Comment: It appears an Rstudio error, see here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200655987-Error-message-while-trying-to-create-a-plot. Try to use the native R, if you have the same error, maybe you will need to reinstall R and Rstudio.